# MySQL convert from UNIXTIME to ISO8601 with timezone

Tags: mysql, timezone, iso8601

I have some dates in MySQL which are stored as UNIXTIME I want to perform a query where the time is returned in ISO8601 format with the timezone. I am aware that using FROM_UNIXTIME will return the time in the local timezone however I have not been able to print the timezone used.

For example when I ask for a timezone no timezone is returned at all.

> mysql  -D foobar_db  --execute "select
>   FROM_UNIXTIME(time_submit,'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') as 'time_submit' from table
>   where id=389580;"
>
> ```
> +----------------------+
> | time_submit          |
> +----------------------+
> | 2014-01-06T14:43:29Z |
> +----------------------+
> ```

This is incredibly frustrating as clearly MySQL knows the timezone when it performs the `FROM_UNIXTIME` conversion. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Edit: It appears ISO8601 defines the timestamp above as being localtime when the offset from UTC is not specified. I want the offset to be returned.

Comment: So far I've come up with the following which seems ugly.  
  
  `SELECT * FROM
( SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(time_submit, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') as time_submit from table where id_job=389580) as time_submit
join
(SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),UTC_TIMESTAMP()) as utc_offset ) as utc_offset`    
  
Which will retrun  
  
`2014-01-06T14:43:29Z 02:00:00`

Comment: ISO8601 defines multiple formats.  Which one in particular are you looking for?  It sounds like you want an expanded timestamp with offset?  If so, what you posted in comments is not the right formatting and could possible be using the wrong offset.  (the *current* offset isn't necessarily the offset related to the data you're returning)

Comment: I completely agree my example above is awful, and as you point out also wrong. I want the format to be the same as when I run `date -iso-8601=s` which returns the format `2014-04-25T08:19:04+0200`